# AS3 - Updating Vars

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, scope

I have a var to get thumbnails width, and it's set at the beggining of my class code.

```
var thumbW:Number;
```

Then I update that var inside a function that updades with stage resize.

```
function x(){
    var thumbW:thumbnails.width;
    //tracing thumbW here returns the updated value. Perfect!
}
```

Then I try to get the **thumbW** value inside a function that scrolls the thumbnails

```
function y(){
    trace(thumbW);
}
```

But, in **y** function, it only returns **NaN**, aka Not a Number, telling me that the value for that variable is not set nor updated.

I'm wondering why this is happening? Why I can't update this var? How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong in your function x.

If you want to access the global variable thumbW, you should direct use it like `thumbW = 123`. Using `var` will declare another local variable inside the function.

And, why you put the flag `thumbnails.width`? There should be compiler error! Typo?

The whole code for function x should be:

```
function x():void {
    thumbW = thumbnails.width;
}
```

BTW, you should learn more about variable scope. There is [an article from adobe help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f8c).

Comment: Thak you, Andy Li! It was a primitive mistake, but sometimes we need a cleared mind to escape from this kind of trap. Thak you, again!!

Comment: also, don't have a function named x() that's going to conflict with tons of stuff!